# List with > 5000 items working with Paging?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-threshold

Not sure if this is a bug or something; I have a List that contains around 12,000 items in SharePoint Online. I was experimenting with it and it seems to still show items using a View with Paging enabled? I have paging of around 1,000 items.

I thought it shouldn't work, cause Paging loads everything? I have another list that contains 6,000 items, but the view is to show all 6,000 items at once. This one shows me the expected List View Threshold.

Is this weird or is it really working as intended? I thought just having >5,000 items in a list will already pose some problems?

**Edit**: I have only 2 columns: Title, and Body.

Answer (score 4):

List view threshold means the maximum rows a single SQL command can read. When you have paging, SQL restricts its reading with the limit functionality added to it. Therefore in your case it would only query 1000 rows at once.

Another thing that I noticed during my researches is that when there is a lookup column, the whole composite table(all rows) is joined before reading the rows. In your case, you do not have lookups so will not be a problem.

Edit: When you filter or group by the lookup column it creates the whole table before displaying the results. Otherwise not.

Comment: Are you sure that when we use paging, row limit defaults to 1000 unless specified?

Comment: Reg. your 2nd point, you mean when there is lookup column in the view field or where clause ?

Comment: Thanks Malin. That's an interesting one; there seems to be differing answers regarding Paging. Others are saying that it still queries ALL of the items, just hiding some of it.

Might it be that the "All Items" default view uses Indexing by default?

Comment: Wait I found some good article about paging. Still could not locate it again.

Comment: Yes when you have a lookup column and in views if you filter by it, it creates the whole table before display the items.

Comment: @MalinDeSilva Does this mean that querying by a lookup is impossible, even when field is indexed, when > 5000 items?

Comment: @eirikb If what Malin said is correct, (my recent experiences say he is) that's exactly what it means.

Comment: Might be obvious to some people, but just wanted to add a quick note on this: If you're filtering your view based on multiple fields joined with an `<And>...</And>` clause, you must get the number of results below 5000 with the first field to prevent the threshold issue. Seems like it builds the table by filtering with the first field, then filters that table based on the second.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the SharePoint Online and you have only 2 column in the lists. Another question are you site collection admin.

If you are Site collection admin then you can see all items as LVTH is different for site collection admin as compare to other users. For Admin by default is 20,000 items while for others are 5000 items.

One thing keep in mind, you have million of items in List but you cannot view more than 5000 items( not for admins) unless you designed it a way which is recommended by MSFT.
Use the Managed Metadata column, index column, filter the views etc.

Check the below link for more information.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2759051/en-us

Comment: Ahhh, yes I am Site Collection Admin. Ok, I will experiment with 20,000 items. Will let you know what happens :)