# SharePoint CAML query to retrieve the item more than threshold limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, list-view-threshold

I facing a problem while retrieving the list data from SharePoint online. I have list items around 20,000. I am using a caml query to retrieve the data based on conditions in dotnet csom. it has 5300 items however I am getting complete 20,000 items see the below code. I have used below logic to over come the list view threshold limit.

```
 var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
 CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
 camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>3000</RowLimit><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AccountRecordType' /><Value Type='Text'>Institution</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='AccountRecordType' /><Value Type='Text'>Group</Value></Eq><Neq><FieldRef Name='MemberStatus' /><Value Type='Text'>Member</Value></Neq></And></Or></Where></View>";
 List<ListItem> lstListItemCollection = new List<ListItem>();

                do
                {
                    ListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    clientContext.Load(listItemCollection);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    //Adding the current set of ListItems in our single buffer
                    lstListItemCollection.AddRange(listItemCollection);
                    //Reset the current pagination info
                    camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = listItemCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition;

                } while (camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);



                foreach (ListItem listItem in lstListItemCollection)
                {

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Query` attribute. In CSOM, we need to use `Query` in CAML.

Try your CAML query as below:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>3000</RowLimit><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AccountRecordType' /><Value Type='Text'>Institution</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='AccountRecordType' /><Value Type='Text'>Group</Value></Eq><Neq><FieldRef Name='MemberStatus' /><Value Type='Text'>Member</Value></Neq></And></Or></Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: Thanks to find out the missing query text. however Now I am getting List view threshold exception while retrieving the data

Comment: Are those columns indexed ? Try decreasing the `Rowlimit` to 100.  Also check out these links  - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/177593/8068 and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C ,

Comment: I have kept Indexed columns before inserting the data to into list. reduced the row limit to 100 and even 50 in caml query. but still giving the same issue. any help ?

Answer (score -1):

**Text field :**

camlQuery.ViewXml = `"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>test</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View>";`

**Date time field :**

camlQuery.ViewXml = `"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Start_x0020_Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>2017-12-21T00:00:00Z</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View>";`