# SharePoint CSOM query against concrete subfolder is not working with RowLimit when thresold is reached

Tags: caml-query, large-lists, row-limit

Can you please help with the following question. I have a document library with a lot of documents (>5000) which are organized in subfolders. I have to query all documents in subfolder. I use this query:

```
"<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
     "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>" + 
     "<Where>" +
           "<Eq>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />" +
                    "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>" +
           "</Eq>" +
     "</Where>" +
"<ViewFields>" +
   "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
   "<FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/>" +
   "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>" +
   "<FieldRef Name='FileRef'/>" +
"</ViewFields>" +
"<RowLimit>50</RowLimit>" +"</View>";
```

The problem is that even subfolder is presented in Where filter this query returns every time 50 items from other subfolders also. It seems that subfolder just ignored and every time 50 items are returned.
I tried to set FolderServerRelativeUrl for camlquery object like this:

```
var query = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml = String.Format(AssignDocuments.GetAllFilesAndSubfoldersQuery, folderUrl),
                FolderServerRelativeUrl = folderUrl
            };
```

But in this case Exception threshold is reached is thrown.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177592/how-to-query-list-with-5000-items-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query list with >5000 items in SharePoint Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177592/how-to-query-list-with-5000-items-in-sharepoint-online)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. No, sorry. I know how to query large list but the problem is I do not want to get all items from library. I need all items from specific folder. But when I put this folder in query I receive threshold error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` if you are already including `FileDirRef` in your CAML.  Remove the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` property.